# how to convert string character to character code in lua?

Tags: lua

I saw some questions about how to convert character code to string character, but my questions is how can I convert string character to character code ?
For example, I want to find the character code of this string character: `str:sub(150, 150)`, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The Bytecode you get with...

```
str:sub(150, 150):byte()
-- A table with complete range of bytecode from str
btab = {str:sub(1, #str):byte(1, #str)}
```

EDIT Better (Applying @lhf and @Luke100000 Comments)
Example typed in Lua Standalone for testing

```
€ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> do local line, code = "how to convert string character to character code in lua?", "" for i = 1, #line do code = code .. ('%s'):format("\\" .. line:byte(i)) end return(code) end
\104\111\119\32\116\111\32\99\111\110\118\101\114\116\32\115\116\114\105\110\103\32\99\104\97\114\97\99\116\101\114\32\116\111\32\99\104\97\114\97\99\116\101\114\32\99\111\100\101\32\105\110\32\108\117\97\63
> line = "how to convert string character to character code in lua?"
> str2b = function(line) local code = "" for i = 1, #line do code = code .. ("\\%s"):format(line:byte(i)) end return(code) end
> code = str2b(line)
> code
\104\111\119\32\116\111\32\99\111\110\118\101\114\116\32\115\116\114\105\110\103\32\99\104\97\114\97\99\116\101\114\32\116\111\32\99\104\97\114\97\99\116\101\114\32\99\111\100\101\32\105\110\32\108\117\97\63
> load(("return '%s'"):format(code))()
how to convert string character to character code in lua?
> line = "Works also with ÜüÄäÖö and ß"
> b2str = function(code) return(load(("return '%s'"):format(code))()) end
> code = str2b(line)
> code
\87\111\114\107\115\32\97\108\115\111\32\119\105\116\104\32\195\156\195\188\195\132\195\164\195\150\195\182\32\97\110\100\32\195\159
> b2str(code)
Works also with ÜüÄäÖö and ß
```

So, if you have that two functions and add them to `string`...

```
string.b2str = b2str
string.str2b = str2b
```

...then they also are string methods...

```
print(("Hello World!"):str2b())
-- \72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33
print(('intruder alert'):upper():sub(10, 10):str2b())
-- \65
-- For all what returning a string
print(os.date():str2b())
-- \83\97\32\50\52\32\68\101\122\32\50\48\50\50\32\49\49\58\53\56\58\48\55\32\67\69\84
```

Comment: `str:byte(150)` is simpler and does not create a temporary string. Also `str:byte(1,-1)` for all bytes.

Comment: Notice that `string.byte` is limited, `8000` bytes for Lua 5.1, `999963` for Lua 5.2 and 5.3 based on local tests.